# How to fix HTML Style overwriting CSS?

Tags: css

I am wanting to show full image opacity on hover. Currently, it is set as 0.6 embedded in the HTML as a code?

I have tried adding an `!important` state to the CSS, it gives me the full opacity but loses the rollover functionality.

This is the HTML giving me issues:

```
<div class="portfolio-image" style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.02868, 1.02868);">
```

This is what I have tried:

```
.portfolio-image{
   opacity:1 !important;
}
```

I would want the opacity to be 1, not 0.6

Comment: <div class="portfolio-image" style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.02868, 1.02868);">

Comment: What about ``opacity: 1;`` ? Remove ``style="display: block; opacity: 0.6; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.02868, 1.02868);"``

Comment: How do you get a roll over effect without transition or hover? There should be a css which is doing the transition or hover. From there, you can change opacity to 1?

Comment: what do you expect to happen for your rollover functionality?  If it is just that the element should go back to being opaque, then you just need to set that in your hover state in your css.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. 

The page in which I am trying to edit is here:

www.designby-dc.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
.portfolio-image {opacity:0.6; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.02868, 1.02868); display:inline-block;}

.portfolio-image:hover {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-image">
  
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
</div>
```

And if you want to apply the css inline in html you just need to update the `hover` css to. where we required `!important`

```
.portfolio-image:hover {opacity:1 !important;}
```

```css
.portfolio-image:hover {opacity:1 !important;}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-image" style="opacity: 0.6; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.02868, 1.02868); display:inline-block;"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
```